# input data in python - get it to stick

Tags: python, input

```
while True:
    print("")
    print("Welcome to Torrey's Restaurant")
    print("=====Select Option to Continue=====")    
    print("1- Reserve a Table")
    print("2- Clear Reservation")
    print("3- Status of Tables")
    print("0- Exit")
    choice = int(input("Choice? "))
    
    count = 0
    tables = []
    name = " "
    
    
    
    for i in range(20):
        tables.append("AVAILABLE")
        
    
    if choice == 0:
        print("Thank you for using this program")
        break
        
    if choice == 1:
        table = int(input("Please select your table number(0-19): "))
        if tables[i] in tables:
            name = input("What is your name?: ")
            tables.insert(table, name)            
        elif name != "AVAILABLE":
            print("The table you selected is unavailable")
```

How can I get the user input data to stick? When a user inputs their name, it inserts itself into the list, however, when the second user attempts to reserve the same table as the first, the original input data is overwritten, and the new data is stored, causing my elif to Never run.

any advice?

Comment: There is the issue of you defining the `tables` inside the while loop and then some issues with how your if-else is working. Check my answer for details and fixes.

Comment: Example., `if tables[i]` should be `if tables[table]` because its the variable `table` that holds the index of the table as input from user. Also, `elif name != "AVAILABLE":` should be either `elif tables[table] != "AVAILABLE"` or just `else` because `name` variable holds the input from user, but you want to check the table index instead.

Comment: Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have tables defined inside the while loop and it resets to the list of "AVAILABLE" each time. Second issue is your if-else loop. I have updated both and marked the differences.

Try this modification -

```
tables = []                            #<---------- defined outside while loop

while True:
    print("")
    print("Welcome to Torrey's Restaurant")
    print("=====Select Option to Continue=====")    
    print("1- Reserve a Table")
    print("2- Clear Reservation")
    print("3- Status of Tables")
    print("0- Exit")
    choice = int(input("Choice? "))
    
    count = 0
    name = " "
    
    for i in range(20):
        tables.append("AVAILABLE")
        
    
    if choice == 0:
        print("Thank you for using this program")
        break
        
    if choice == 1:
        table = int(input("Please select your table number(0-19): "))
        if tables[table] == 'AVAILABLE':           #<--------- check if table available
            name = input("What is your name?: ")
            tables.insert(table, name)             #<--------- insert name at position of table
        else:                                      #<--------- else error message
            print("The table you selected is unavailable")
```

Here is a demo result of when the same table #1 is selected by a new user.

```
Welcome to Torrey's Restaurant
=====Select Option to Continue=====
1- Reserve a Table
2- Clear Reservation
3- Status of Tables
0- Exit
Choice? 1
Please select your table number(0-19): 1
What is your name?: John

Welcome to Torrey's Restaurant
=====Select Option to Continue=====
1- Reserve a Table
2- Clear Reservation
3- Status of Tables
0- Exit
Choice? 1
Please select your table number(0-19): 1
The table you selected is unavailable

Welcome to Torrey's Restaurant
=====Select Option to Continue=====
1- Reserve a Table
2- Clear Reservation
3- Status of Tables
0- Exit
Choice? 0
Thank you for using this program
```

Once done, printing the `tables` variable should retain the values that you want -

```
print(tables)
```

```
['AVAILABLE', 'John', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 
 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 
 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 
 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 
 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 
 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 
 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 
 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 
 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE', 'AVAILABLE']
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a list, use a `dict`. The keys are table numbers (`1, 2, ..., n`); the values are availability status (e.g. `AVAILABLE, BUSY, ...`). Checking whether a table is occupied or not then becomes an average-case constant time operation, and you can still access table states (and occupant names) by using that class' `values` and `keys` methods.

```
from enum import Enum, auto


NUMBER_OF_TABLES = 20

# If we know a thing can only be in one of N states,
# an enum.Enum object gives us an easy tool to enforce
# that constraint.
class TableStatus(Enum):
    AVAILABLE = auto()
    BUSY = auto()


# All tables start available. We're using a tuple
# here to pair the status-name pairs, but it'd be 
# more readable if you used a NamedTuple-based class
# to store things in an easier-to-interpret format.
tables = {
    idx: (TableStatus.AVAILABLE, "")
    for idx in range(NUMBER_OF_TABLES)
}

# Prompt for a table.
check_table = input("What table do you want? ")

try:
    check_table = int(check_table)
    if tables[check_table][0] == TableStatus.AVAILABLE:
        name = input("What's your name? ")
        tables[check_table] = (TableStatus.BUSY, name)
    elif tables[check_table][0] == TableStatus.BUSY:
        # Handle the busy case.
        print(
            "Sorry, that table's already occupied. "
            f"The occupant's {tables[check_table][1]}."
        )
except KeyError:  # The customer asked for a table number we don't have.
    print("Sorry, that table doesn't exist.")
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have mentioned this. This is a school assignment, we have not yet covered functions. Instructor may not accept functions at this point. My apologies.

Comment: I see. In that case: in the context of your original problem, notice that `tables[i]` is *always* in `tables`. You don't want to check whether the element is in the list: you want to check whether the *value* at that element is `AVAILABLE`. If I ask you for table `x`, you should check whether `tables[x]` is available for me to sit in. In your current implementation, _every_ insert creates a _new_ table (not what you want).

Comment: I'd also note that you don't need to store occupancy status *and* occupant name. Given `n` tables, store `n` occupant names, with the caveat that an unoccupied table has no occupant name (e.g. `["John", None, "Jack", "Jill"]` has four tables, of which one is unoccupied. As your model becomes more complicated (e.g. a table can be busy even if it's unoccupied, like when a table is being bussed), you'd need to relax this assumption.

Comment: if I am understanding this correctly, instead of validating the name in my elif, I should check the status of tables[x]?

Comment: Instead of checking whether `tables[i] in tables`, you should check whether `tables[i] == "AVAILABLE"`. If it's available, the requestor occupies it (and you mark it as busy). If it's not available, the requestor should be prompted for a different table (or—if all tables are busy—asked to try again later). Note that you should *not* use `insert` to mark occupancy,  since that _adds a new table_ to the set of tables.

Comment: I hadn't noticed this, but you are correct, tables.insert adds a table at the end. is there any way to update a table without using a function? I originally had tables.append(name)